# How to get full name of key field(country name) in HTML Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, lodash

I am using Angular js, Lodash. So I am calling one API, API has json data like below.

```
[{ "_id":"zw",
   "name":"Zimbabwe"   
},
{ "_id":"au",
   "name":"Australia"   
},
{ "_id":"in",
   "name":"India"   
}]
```

I have written one function for mapping country code respective of full form of countries.

```
$scope.CountryHashmap  =  _.reduce(res,  function (hash,  value)  {
          var  key  =  value['_id'];
          hash[key]  =  value['name'];
          return  hash;
        },  {});
```

After putted _.reduce function below is the mapped data:

```
{
"zw":"Zimbabwe",
"au":"Australia",
"in":"india"
```

}

In html page I have already country code, So I want to put full name of country place of codes.

**HTML**:

```
{{countryCode}}
```

CountryCode like au,in and zw.

Comment: So, What is the question ?!

Comment: don't understand what do you want?

Comment: @SameerAhmad Thanks for the comment. I have already country codes in html page. So I want to put full name of country in html page.

Comment: please share the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get name from $scope.CountryHashmap then $scope.CountryHashmap return country name from object.

```
 {{CountryHashmap[countryCode]}}
```

you can also create function.

```
$scope.getName(code){
    if(code)
        return $scope.CountryHashmap[code];
}
```

No clear what do you want. :P

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, just pass country codes `key` to mapped data array like `mappedDataArr[key]`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) { 
    $scope.mappedDataArr = {
      "zw":"Zimbabwe",
      "au":"Australia",
      "in":"india"
    };
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span>{{ mappedDataArr['in'] }}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```